# Import csv into mysql related tables

Tags: laravel, workbench

I have a csv to register users with more than 1000 rows but I need to import them in several related tables.

The tables are

```
hotsite_users_data
points_account
users
```

`users` have the columns `hotsite_users_data_id` and `points_account_id` where it stores related information and their id is automatically generated.

Table structure

```
Users = id,email,password,hotsite_user_data_id,points_account_id,created_at
hotsite_user_data = id,name,email,created_at
points_account = id,type,balance,created_at
```

I use the workbench to access the database.

Excel rows

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a picture of some rows of the excel

Comment: post edited with rows excel

Comment: Okay, so, what happends if you import right away the csv into the users table?

Comment: it will be necessary to inform the id of the hotsite_users_data table where it contains information about the name and a row generated from points_account.